# Asterisk - inbound calls from SIP DID trunk "rejected because extension not found"

Tags: voip, asterisk, sip

I have a DID with DIDforSale that's pointed at my Asterisk server. When I call it from my landline phone I get the AT&T disconnected line recording. The Asterisk CLI shows the error message:

```
[Oct  6 17:03:00] NOTICE[10563]: chan_sip.c:20163 handle_request_invite: Call from 'didforsale_1' to extension '###########' rejected because extension not found.
```

The "from" part indicates it's correctly matching the `sip.conf` peer entry. The "to" part shows that the peer is correctly sending the DID number as the target extension. The DID number is a valid extension in the peer's incoming context (details below) so I can only assume that Asterisk is looking in the wrong context.

#### Configuration

I'm using Asterisk 1.6.2.5-0ubuntu1.4 installed via Apt on a physical server running Ubuntu Server 10.04 (lucid). I have the trunk configured in `sip.conf` with one peer per originating IP (there are two). These are the relevant stanzas:

```
[didforsale_base](!)
    type=peer
    context=from-did
    nat=no
    insecure=port,invite

    ; configure codecs
    disallow=all
    allow=ulaw
    allow=alaw
    allow=g729
    dtmfmode=rfc2833

[didforsale_1](didforsale_base)
    host=AAA.AAA.AAA.AAA

[didforsale_2](didforsale_base)
    host=BBB.BBB.BBB.BBB
```

The peers are configured to send calls to the `from-did` context, which contains an extension per DID number. The context is configured in `extensions.ael` like this:

```
// starting context for calls originating from DID trunks
// the call is matched on the DID number and routed appropriately
context from-did {
    // test DID from DIDforSale
    ########### => jump s@inbound;
}
```

#### Debug Output

With `core set verbose 5`, `core set debug 5`, and `sip set debug on` the only additional CLI output besides the SIP packet dumps is:

```
  == Using SIP RTP CoS mark 5
Sending to AAA.AAA.AAA.AAA : 5060 (no NAT)
Using INVITE request as basis request - 1510862529_23265@CCC.CCC.CCC.CCC
Found peer 'didforsale_1' for '+###########' from AAA.AAA.AAA.AAA:5060
Found RTP audio format 18
Found RTP audio format 0
Found RTP audio format 101
Found audio description format G729 for ID 18
Found audio description format PCMU for ID 0
Found audio description format telephone-event for ID 101
Capabilities: us - 0x10c (ulaw|alaw|g729), peer - audio=0x104 (ulaw|g729)/video=0x0 (nothing)/text=0x0 (nothing), combined - 0x104 (ulaw|g729)
Non-codec capabilities (dtmf): us - 0x1 (telephone-event), peer - 0x1 (telephone-event), combined - 0x1 (telephone-event)
Peer audio RTP is at port CCC.CCC.CCC.CCC:5432
```

#### Prior Troubleshooting

I've verified with `sip show peer didforsale_1` that the peers are using the correct context. `dialplan show from-did` indicates that the context parsed correctly. If I include it in the default context for my desk phone calling the DID number gives me the IVR menu as expected.

I read the first several pages of Google results for a few sets of search terms around the error message but didn't find anything useful. It's mostly people using FreePBX or a similar product needing help setting up the equivalent of my `from-did` context in the GUI. A few posts look like they could be the same problem I'm having, but none of them have answers. I would post links but my reputation is too low. Once it's high enough I'll edit to add them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up reading the source for the `handle_request_invite` function from `chan_sip.c` mentioned in the error message. That function calls `get_destination` (in the same file) to resolve the destination address. If `get_destination` returns an error it produces the error message I was seeing.

The domain of the URI in the incoming SIP `INVITE` request from the DID provider is set to the IP address of my PBX, not its domain. I had `allowexternaldomains` disabled in `sip.conf` and my IP wasn't in the domain list so the destination address was being rejected. Looking at the source for `get_destination` it looks like that should produce an error message at debug level 1 before returning the error, but for some reason I'm not seeing it.

Adding my IP address to the domain list seems to have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The thing I see at the moment with the numbers hidden is the difference between the numbers and the numbers with the + prepended.

The easiest test to see if this is the problem would be something like:

```
// starting context for calls originating from DID trunks
// the call is matched on the DID number and routed appropriately
context from-did {
    // test DID from DIDforSale
    ########### => jump s@inbound;
    +########### => jump s@inbound;
}
```

or the 'what did I miss' option logging:

```
// starting context for calls originating from DID trunks
// the call is matched on the DID number and routed appropriately
context from-did {
    // test DID from DIDforSale
    _.+ => NoOp(debug incoming exten = ${EXTEN})
    _.+ => jump s@inbound;
}
```

This will log the actual extension to your console. Using _.+ is frowned upon (because it matches everything) and will give you a warning.

The + is from the ITU standard for publishing international phone numbers. Different SIP providers will have different ways of dealing with this. But the fact that you mention AT&T (a US based company) and use 10 # signs for the number give me the hint that the core of the problem is the difference between the notation usual in the US for long distance dialing: 1-NNN-YYY-ZZZZ and the ITU international notation +1-NNN-YYY-ZZZZ.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity; I probably should have obscured the phone numbers the same way I did the IP addresses. The number in the dialplan and the error message is the DID number in US 1+10D format with no punctuation. The one will the + in the debug output is the landline number that I was calling from in US 1+10D format with no other punctuation. I'll try your suggestion for logging with `NoOp` and a catch-all extension.